# Вывести массив чисел без повторений

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Дан отсортированный по возрастанию массив C (например, {2, 2, 2, 3, 3}). Нужно вывести в консоль этот же массив C без повторений (то есть должно получиться просто 2 3).

Я, честно, пытался это сделать, но у меня всегда появляется 1-2 лишних цифры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идея формирования нового массива перебиранием каждого элемента C, но это вряд ли хорошее решение в плане скорости работы.
Как лучше поступить? Могу скинуть полный исходник, если нужно.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < size; j++) {
        if (C[i] != C[j]) {
            cout << C[j] << " ";
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Он же **отсортированный** - выводить нужно только смены значений:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[] = {1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,8};

    cout << a[0] << " ";
    for(int last = a[0], i = 1; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] == last) continue;
        cout << (last = a[i]) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Или, с применением стандартной библиотеки - в одну строку:

```
copy(begin(a),unique(begin(a),end(a)),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 10):

Продолжая хороший ответ от `Harry`, если пользоваться стандартными альгоритмами, то проще:

```
unique_copy(begin(a), end(a), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Comment: Интересно, кто-то помнит наизусть всю стандартную библиотеку? :) Меня всегда утешают слова Страуструпа - "чтоб хорошо программировать, не требуется знать весь язык полностью" или как-то так...

Comment: @Harry,  я не знаю   С++17  и выше, забываю многое из того, что  знаю, но альгоритмы и контейнеры в моем ежедневном меню. Я не знаю даже половину того, что знаете вы, но  не вы и ни кто либо не сможет знать  весь язык. Но в данном случаи, я уверен, что вы знаете, и вам не нужны утешения.

Comment: Ну что вам сказать... У меня практическое программирование, увы, в ежедневное меню вообще не входит :( Так что все мои навыки/знания etc - так, чисто из любви к программированию вообще и C++ в частности... Наверное, я потому так и активничаю здесь - что это для меня отдушина, позволяющая хоть так заняться любимым занятием :)

Comment: И опять же сошлюсь на Страуструпа - из частного письма: "Life is not just computing" :)

Answer (score 8):

Предлагаю реализацию немного лучше чем у Harry

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int a[] = {1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,8};

cout << a[0] << ' ';
for(int i = 1; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
{
    if (a[i] !=a[i-1]) cout<<a[i]<<' ';
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int array[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10 };

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); ++ i)
{
    // Начиная со второго все элементы проверяем на равенство с предыдущим, если равен, то пропускаем
    if (i > 0 && array[i] == array[i - 1])
        continue;

    std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:
1
2
3
4
8
9
10

Comment: И вам спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ну начинайте цикл с 1 и проверку  i > 0  не нужно будет выполнять. Анологичен первому ответу

Answer (score 0):

Мда... А не проще сделать так:

```
int* mass = new int[11]{ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7 };
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
         if (mass[i] != mass[i + 1]) {
             cout << mass[i] <<  " ";
            
         }
    }
```

Вывод: 1 2 3 5 7